# What is the social context of "pizzazz"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, slang

The word can also be written "pzaz" and "pizazz". I have found some definitions, but I want a synonym. As English is not my natural tongue, I also don't exactly know what it means socially. Is it the same as *je ne sais quois*?

Comment: I checked at least 8 of them. Specially the ones that are created collaboratively to get the slang words.

Comment: *Pizzazz* (the only spelling I've ever seen) isn't at all the same as *je ne sais quoi* - which obviously refers to some unknown/indescribable quality. But sticking with French words that have crossed over into English, I think **elan** comes pretty close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pizzazz) has a few synonyms, grouped into two basic meanings:

> **1.** energy; vitality; vigor.
>   **2.** attractive style; dash; flair.

Though this word is informal, it can be used at its face value socially - it's a positive term (as evidenced by the second definition above) and not crude.

As a side note, *pizzazz* is definitely the [most common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pizazz,pizzazz,pzazz,pzaz,pizzaz&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) spelling of this word:

[image]

Comment: The thing is that sometimes I don't really know if I understand the social context of the words. Thats why I'm asking for help.

Comment: where did you get that graph? Looks great.

Comment: The link above it shows where to get such graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Sparkle, excitement, energy.  I've never seen it spelled pzaz.  That sounds like it was seen in a text message.

Comment: How about [pzazz](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pzazz)?